# PHP - pregmatch array from json_encode for str_replace() and return it to array as well

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array:

```
 $form = array(
    array(
       "type" => "text",
       "value" => "
         Hello @name

         How old are you? @age

         How are you today? @condition"
    ),
    array(
       "type" => "font",
       "family" => "Arial",
       "size" => 6,
       "weight" => "Bold"
    )
 );
```

Then I did this `json_encode($form)` and It has this output:

```
 [ 
  {
   "type":"text",
   "value":"\r\n Hello @name\r\n\r\n How old are you? @age\r\n \r\n How are you today? @condition"
  },
  {
   "type":"font",
   "family":"Arial",
   "size":6,
   "weight":"Bold"
  }
 ]
```

The thing is `json_encode()` also acts like a string so I can also do like this:

```
 $old = array('@name','@age',@condition');
```

This `$old` data is what I will put in the `str_replace();`

But I want to do it in an array form like get all data with `@` symbol.

Can we do that with pregmatch? or is there any other way to do it?

Comment: in `str_replace` yu can pass array as well.

Comment: yeah i already done that sir, but I wanted it to be like dynamic or something to get all the data `@` signs on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, You can get list of words that start with `@` by using [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)
I would use a function like this to help me get data from any type of input :

```
/**
* We will take two param on this function
* $input is the data we will be look into
* $tags is reference to a array, we will store out result in this array.
*/
function fetch_tags($input, &$tags){
    if(is_array($input)){
        // If input is array, iterate it and pass the value to fetch_tags function
        foreach($input as $key => $value ){
            fetch_tags($value, $tags);
        }

        return true;
    }elseif(is_string($input)){
        /**
        * If its a string, we can preg_match now.
        * \@\S+ means we will take any string which follows a @
        * If we get any matches, we will store that result in $tags
        */
        if(preg_match_all('#(\@\S+)#', $input, $matches)){
            $tags = array_merge($tags, $matches[1]);
        }

        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Example :

```
<?php

$form = array(
    array(
       "type" => "text",
       "value" => "
         Hello @name

         How old are you? @age

         How are you today? @condition"
    ),
    array(
       "type" => "font",
       "family" => "Arial",
       "size" => 6,
       "weight" => "Bold"
    )
 );

$words = [];

fetch_tags($form, $words);

print_r($words);
```

Output would be :

```
Array
(
  [0] => @name
  [1] => @age
  [2] => @condition
)
```

Comment: Thanks alot mate! :)